# Migrating 0.9 Apache Kafka Cluster to Confluent Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform

I am currently planning out a upgrade/migration of our Apache Kafka cluster to a Confluent Kafka based one. Our current cluster is 0.9
 is 0.10.
Is it possible to simply decommission a old broker and reintroduce the upgraded confluent broker with the same broker id in-place?

I am aware of the protocol version settings which have already been set on both old and ew broker.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Apache Kafka 0.9 formed the basis of Confluent Platform 2.0, and Apache Kafka 0.10 was Confluent Platform 3.0. It's not clear from your question which you're actually using. 
Either way, [the documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/4.0.0/installation/upgrade.html) gives you the process to follow.

Comment: Sorry, I'm aware of the change. I am upgrading from Apache-Kafka v0.8 to Confluent-Kafka v0.10. THe question is specifically, instead of adding brokers to a cluster, is there any expectation of issues if I were to simply shut down a old broker with old Apache-Kafka, and start a new broker with the new Confluent Kafka with the same broker ID. Normally in this scenario, assuming the versions are the same, Kafka would simply replicate the partitions onto the replaced broker. I'm just not sure if this is viable with this Platform shift + version upgrade

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "Confluent Kafka".

You can refer to the [Upgrade section of Kafka 0.10 documentation](http://kafka.apache.org/0102/documentation.html#upgrade), and simply apply that for the package that you download from Confluent site rather than the Apache site.

---

> Is it possible to simply decommission a old broker and reintroduce the upgraded confluent broker with the same broker id in-place

Not really. Then you lose all partitions on that old broker.